# iOS - Best way to track multiple loading states of different components within the same ViewModel in SwiftUI & MVVM?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm

So I basically have one ViewModel for an entire screen which has multiple components with data coming from different API requests / Endpoints.

What im currently doing is having an Observable object to which I suscribe to changes from the View (typical state SwiftUI state handling) and emit changes through @Published properties. Rough Example:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
     @Published private(set) var isFirstComponentLoading = true
     @Published private(set) var isSecondComponentLoading = true
     @Published private(set) var isThirdComponentLoading = true

     @Published private(set) var firstComponent: FirstComponentModel?
     private var api = SomeApi()

     //Imagine the exact same for every other component
     func loadFirstComponent() {
       isfirstComponentLoading = true
       Task { 
           let response = try await api.loadFirstComponent()
           await MainActor.run { 
               firstComponentModel = response
               isFirstComponentLoading = false
           }
       }
     }
}
```

View (super standard stuff):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
         if vm.isFirstComponentLoading {
             LoadingView()
        } else { 
          FirstComponentView()
        }
    }
}
```

While this seems to be working perfectly,I have 2 questions:

- Im not proud of having one variable for each loading status + another variable to also hold the model of the component, wondering whats the best way to track multiple loading states within the same ViewModel, I feel like Im missing something here?
- How would I go about being able to run custom code once all requests have successfuly finished?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use an enum like this:

```swift
enum LoadableResource<Value> {
  case notLoaded
  case loading
  case loaded(Value)
}
```

Then you don’t need to maintain two variables per option, which could end up in an illegal state (think having the `isPropertyOneLoading` state being `true`, while `propertyOne` actually has a value)

You could then just `switch` over the current state of your `LoadableResource` in your view.

Comment: Interesting! Could you provide an example on how to use this from the View? Lets say I have an array of LoadableResources in my ViewModel such as @Published var components: [LoadableResource<Value>], how would you go about initializing this array and using it from the View?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to know a better way to do this, but currently I do this by keeping a count of how many requests I am running in the background, and decrease the count when each request completes. When the `RunningCount` is equal to 0 I update the `IsLoading` Bool to toggle my loading indicator on my view that all the data is available.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var RunningCount: Int = 0
    @Published public var IsLoading: Bool = true
    
    @Published private(set) var firstComponent: ListFirstComponentModel?
    private var api = SomeApi()
    
    init(){
        //Imagine the exact same for every other component
        self.RunningCount+=1
        Task {
            let response = try await api.loadFirstComponent()
            await MainActor.run {
                firstComponentModel = response
                self.RunningCount-=1
                if self.RunningCount <= 0 {
                    self.IsLoading = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The individual loadingStatus could be set on each individual object by extracting `FirstComponentModel` into `ListFirstComponentModel` which would get set from `api.loadFirstComponent()`

```
struct ListFirstComponentModel {
    // store request loading status
    var loadingStatus: Bool = false
    // store api data here
    var data: [FirstComponentModel] = []
}
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, although I need to be notified exactly when each component finishes loading so I can add/remove each component LoadingView individually. This notifies me only when everything has finished loading and only then triggers a View update.

Comment: Ah my bad, I misunderstood and only answered the second question. Yeah having a different published bool for each isn't a bad approach, I've done that as-well, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

Comment: No worries, thanks for replying :). Im now doing @Published var loadingStatus: [Component: Bool] = [:] and setting that dict instead. That simplifies having one loading variable per component, but I still feel like theres a better way haha.

Comment: I guess you could also make a published ListFirstComponentModel with a var for loadingStatus: Bool, and data: [FirstComponentModel] <- (for api data)

Answer (score 0):

`@StateObject` is not designed for a legacy view model object you'll need to learn the `View` struct hierarchy otherwise you'll basically be trying to reimplement what SwiftUI View structs already do: dependency and change tracking.

To use async/await in SwiftUI don't use `Task {}` use the proper task and `task(id: someChangingValue)` modifiers but to do that first you need to remove that view model object, make a View struct hierarchy and use @State in a parent View and pass down let for read and Binding for read/write. Use computed properties to transform data from rich model types to simple types on the way down. That way you can make Previews that use simple types.

You can put a api/manager/controller in an EnvironmentKey, e.g. like the built-in authorizationController.